# Does $\frac{1}{z^n}$ have a primitive on $\mathbb{D} - 0$ for $n < 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I'm studying complex analysis from Stein and Shakarachi. There is a question that asks you to evaluate:
$\int_{\gamma} z^{n}\ \mathrm{d}z$ for all integer *n*, where $\gamma$ is any circle centered about the origin. Clearly $n \geq 0 \Rightarrow$ there exists a primitive, which implies the integral around any closed loop is 0. For $n = -1$ the integral is $2\pi i$. For $n < 1$ the integral appears to be 0, since we get:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\gamma} z^{n}\ \mathrm{d}z & = \int_{0}^{2\pi} (re^{it})^{n} (rie^{it})\ \mathrm{d}t\\
& = \int_{0}^{2\pi} ir^{n+1} e^{it(n+1)}\ \mathrm{d}t\\
& = \frac{r^{n+1}}{n+1} \times (e^{2\pi i(n+1)} - 1) = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since $e^{2\pi i n}$ = 1. What's wrong with the calculation? I'm pretty sure $z^{n}$ for $n < -1$ shouldn't have a primitive since they all have a singularity at $z = 0$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The primitive of $z^{-n}$ for $n>1$ is $z^{1-n}/(1-n)$.

Comment: So what you're saying is nothing is wrong with the calculation and it is in fact 0? Then may I ask, what is wrong with $z^{-1}$? Why doesn't it have a primitive? Don't they all have a singularity at $z = 0$.

Comment: $z^{-1}$ has the logarithm as a primitive, and the "singularity" is worse: one cannot define the logarithm on any open set in inside $\Bbb C^\times$ that contains a loop that encloses the origin.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. Thank you so much. Guess I'll try learning next why that is in fact the case. I imagine because $log\ z = log\ r + i\theta$ and $\theta$ isn't uniquely determined at $z = 0$.